# mysql foreign key constraint fails when disabled

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm having a problem restoring data into a mysql DB from a dump. I'm running the same version of mysql, I have disabled foreign key checks, and data types are the same, but I can't understand why the check fails

```
Error in foreign key constraint of table staging/bookmarks:
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `bookmarks_video_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
```

table schema

```
-- Server version   5.6.34-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

...

--
-- Table structure for table `bookmarks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bookmarks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bookmarks` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `video_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `course_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bookmarks_course_id_user_id_video_id_time_unique` (`course_id`,`user_id`,`video_id`,`time`),
  KEY `bookmarks_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `bookmarks_video_id_foreign` (`video_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bookmarks_course_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `bookmarks_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `bookmarks_video_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


...


--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hours_watched` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


....


--
-- Table structure for table `videos`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `videos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_public` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_visible` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `duration` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `provider_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `presenter_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `level_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hd_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `high_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `transcript_file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `prefix_title` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `jwplayer_mediaid` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `videos_level_id_foreign` (`level_id`),
  KEY `videos_provider_id_foreign` (`provider_id`),
  KEY `videos_presenter_id_foreign` (`presenter_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `videos_level_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`level_id`) REFERENCES `levels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `videos_presenter_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`presenter_id`) REFERENCES `presenters` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `videos_provider_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`provider_id`) REFERENCES `providers` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


...

/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
```

Comment: Very curious. It's a dump so, obviously, it was working and there's nothing wrong with the definition. Works in 5.7.21 and whatever version of 5.6 that sqlfiddle is on  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/985dce/1.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the table you want to reference (`users`) before you can declare a foreign key to it.

In your case, you are creating the table `bookmarks` before the other table `users` exists.

The error you got has nothing to do with the `foreign_key_checks` being disabled vs. enabled.

---

Actually, I have to correct my answer. This dump file should work fine, and does work fine when I test it in my local MySQL 5.6 instance.

The way it gets around the foreign key ordering problem is this:

```
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

This disables enforcement of the foreign key rules until the enforcement is restored at the end:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
```

All I can suggest is that something in the spaces where you have `...` is restoring foreign key enforcement too soon. You need to examine your complete file and figure that out.

Comment: ok - that's what I was thinking but wasn't positive, is there a way to order the mysqldump schema so an import will not have this issue?

Comment: I've grep'd for foreign key in the dump - its ~ 1.2G in size - but I wasn't able to find any other reference that would be restoring enforcement.  I'll have to keep looking.  I could probably do two dumps, one to recreate the schema and one to add the data and see if I can isolate the problem that way?